# Google Drive not responding with size for file download

Tags: download, http, google-drive

I have two zip files hosted on Google Drive that are publicly accessible over the internet. They are [here](https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B9Hi1LzOUyXmSm9XUGE4amZEZDg) and [here](https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B9Hi1LzOUyXmZUwxaGh2ZklDQ3M).

For some reason, the first file is not returning the content-Length header with the response, so when downloading the file I can't read the size to display progress.

The second file works fine. I've tested this with my own download code, Chrome and another download manager. None of them are receiving the size of the first file when downloading but all work correctly with the second, so it must be a Google Drive issue.

Why is Google Drive behaving in this way? How can I resolve it.

Comment: You should be using the Google Drive API to download files like this.

Comment: @Ramhound why's that? That's not going to resolve the content-length header issue.

Comment: You won't need to use content-length information you can just determine the size through the API.  Why is that?  Because that is the proper way to download a file, within a program, that exists on Google Drive.

Comment: @Ramhound I have a generic download method already written, why add it more code that I have to test? Google Drive supports direct downloads over HTTP so why not just do that? Why should I need to make the extra call to the server? It also give me the flexibility of moving my hosting off Google Drive with zero effort.

Comment: Without seeing your code and how it works, its difficult to explain the behavior, hence the reason I suggest avoid your code and use the Google API.

Comment: @Ramhound My code is not the problem here. The problem here is Google Drive not returning the Content-Length header for one file.

Comment: I'm using the v3 API, copied the Python code from the Google's site and I have the same problem. The API call never completes because (as it took me a while to discover), the HTTP call doesn't return the Content-Length. Any solutions?